# Does Spring 4.1 MVC have Cors support?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know I can add Cors support through a filter like this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/.

I don't know when that guide was created and whether a later version comes with an implementation of Cors inbuilt...

Answer (score 5):

[Create this class](https://gist.github.com/zeroows/80bbe076d15cb8a4f0ad).

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        // CORS "pre-flight" request
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    //  response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1");
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

And add this to your web.xml

```
<!-- Add this to your web.xml to enable "CORS" -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <filter-class>tk.aalkhodiry.filters.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any built-in spring CORS filters, but f.e. apache has an implementation for it (I doubt that for JBOSS, Glassfish... there isn't any). If you use tomcat, put this in your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,Authorization, X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Set the params for your preferences, and don't forget to enable CORS on the client as well.
Additionally, if you use Spring Security, make sure the SS filterChain is AFTER the CorsFilter setting (sometimes failed without it)

Hope this helped, good luck

Comment: worked for me ,  prefer Aalkhodiry way, but used this.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Framework 4.1 only has builtin CORS support for [SockJS](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-fallback-cors) and allows to [specify a list of allowed origins](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketHandlerRegistration.html#setAllowedOrigins-java.lang.String...-) for both Websocket and SockJS.

First class CORS support is available as of [Spring Framework 4.2 GA](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/31/spring-framework-4-2-goes-ga). See [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) for more details.